# REST URI for resources with n:n relationships

Tags: api, rest

I have 2 entities in my API:

/users
/groups

And they have an n:n relationship. I want to know which URI would be better to access this relationship that we can call 'membership':

- /groups/{group_id}/members/{user_id}

OR

- /memberships/{membership_id}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the KISS principle, I would say the second. But are you sure the client application always has knowledge of the membershipid?

Or would this mean a second call because it needed to fetch properties of a user or group? Then I would say go for the first one (unless that takes several calls to your endpoint as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, I guess that I'll go for the first approach then, since the client app would have it easier to access the group_id and the user_id.